# Can a question begin with "to"?

Tags: word-order, tag-questions

To whom should we complain about a robbery in the neighborhood?

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

This usually shows up in formal speech/writing, because it's usually a way of avoiding ending a sentence with a preposition, and many still avoid that in formal writing:

> Who should we complain about a robbery in the neighbourhood to?

Except you can get the 'to' away from the end of the sentence more easily, and that sentence is awkward (though people will still say it), but then people might argue about what other than a sentence shouldn't end with a preposition:

> Who should we complain to about about a robbery in the neighbourhood?

That's probably the most natural way to say it. However, the *to whom* version is understood and natural in some dialects and contexts:

> To whom should be we complain about a robbery in the neighbourhood?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is right(correct) as a formal beginning of a posting or letter, in my opinion. It is probably not appropriate otherwise.